# uploading large files with javascript and php

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload, base64, chunks

I have an uploaded image that I put in a canvas, 
and let the user create rectangles above the image,I would like to store the image and the rectangles data (position, size, angle...),
so I have `image` in input and an array of object `rects[]`,what I was doing is posting the base64 format in ajax with the array, but I found out, that is not a good idea since I exceeded the limit size of posting data, after some research , I found that there is maybe a way where I can send this data in chunks but I don't understand exactly what does mean and how the server side will receive data, will I keep everything the same in server side or should I handle that too,please can someone help me on this and give me some solution, or explain me how to send in chunks ?

Comment: Sending data in chunks is not possible unless the receiving server side application is capable of handling such a load. You'll most likely have to write your own solution.

Comment: what kind of solution ? and can you tell me what happen in server side when we use chunks ?

Comment: A server which accepts files in chunks.